# Does unicode have a ee character like ꜳ (U+A733, latin aa)?

Tags: unicode

Does unicode have a ee character like ꜳ ([U+A733, latin aa](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A733/index.htm))?

Either Google is no good with stuff under 3 letters, or it really doesn’t exist.

Comment: See [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/) or [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

Comment: Sorry for posting in the wrong section... Last time I was in stackexchange I'd bet there was half of the sections today!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn’t. The “ꜳ” was introduced by the “[Proposal to add medievalist characters to the UCS](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc2/wg2/docs/n3027.pdf).” No ee-counterpart was introduced in that proposal or in any other. I am not a french(?) speaker so I can't say if that makes sense.

Here are some pointers for helping you search for such a thing:

- Look in Wikipedia, there is a good chance you will find a similar letter linking a relevant source (in case of ꜳ, the above document was linked on the french site).
- Google the full name of the character, ꜳ is called "LATIN LETTER AA". Other Code points follow this schema too. Googling "LETTER EE" should do the trick.
- Look in the same block. Similar characters are more likely to be near each other.

Comment: I had some trouble finding aa to begin with (found it in a huge unicode chart), so kept wondering if I just missed. Thanks for your time and help!